# I need to split a line from a CSV with a batch file, but it has empty values that need to be preserved

Tags: string, batch-file, dos, batch-processing, split

I'm writing a batch file which takes the lines from a CSV and rearranges them into a new CSV for import to Excel.

My difficulty is that empty elements are ignored, but it's important for me to preserve the empty elements in the table that CSV was produced from, so that I can pull the correct values for import.

Here's a simplified example of my problem: Let's say I have a file, input.txt, with the contents:

```
1,2,,4
```

And here's my code:

```
@echo off

set filename=input.txt

for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %%a in (%filename%) do (
  echo a : %%a
  echo b : %%b
  echo c : %%c
  echo d : %%d
)
```

My output is:

```
a : 1
b : 2
c : 4
d :
```

I would like the output:

```
a : 1
b : 2
c : 
d : 4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can try to replace the empty spots with another string (like `[filler_string]`) that you can filter it out later

Comment: PowerShell is probably the easiest way to get what you want (`Import-Csv`).

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set filename=input.txt

for /F "delims=" %%x in (%filename%) do (
   set line=%%x
   for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %%a in ("!line:,,=,"",!") do (
      echo a : %%~a
      echo b : %%~b
      echo c : %%~c
      echo d : %%~d
   )
)
```

Comment: The OP should realise that two empty fields in a row will not be handled.

Comment: foxidrive is correct - it will not handle consecutive empty fields. Easily solved by using `FOR ... IN (""!line:^,^=","!"") DO ...`

Comment: Also, the above will fail if the first column is empty. The "solution" in my first comment will fail if any values are already quoted. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24316919/1012053) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let's assume you have a simple case where none of the values contain quotes, commas, or `!`. Then you could use:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "filename=input.csv"

for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%filename%") do (
  set "ln=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (""!ln:^,^=","!"") do (
    echo a : %%~a
    echo b : %%~b
    echo c : %%~c
    echo d : %%~d
  )
)
```

The above will not work properly if some of the column values are already quoted. Aacini has code that works in some cases, but it fails if there are consecutive empty columns, or if there is a leading empty column. A bit more code solves those shortcommings:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "filename=input.csv"

for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%filename%") do (
  set "ln=%%a"
  if "!ln:~0,1!" equ "," set "ln=""!ln!"
  if "!ln:~-1,1!" equ "," set "ln=!ln!"""  %== I don't think this is needed, but it can't hurt ==%
  set "ln=!ln:,,=,"",!"
  set "ln=!ln:,,=,"",!"
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=, eol=," %%a in ("!ln!") do (
    echo a : %%~a
    echo b : %%~b
    echo c : %%~c
    echo d : %%~d
  )
)
```

But CSV files can be tricky. Any column value may be quoted, and quoted values may contain commas, newlines, or quotes escaped as `""`. Also, expansion of FOR /F variables containing `!` (or possibly `^`) will corrupt the value if delayed expansion is enabled. Solving all of these issues is extremely difficult using pure native batch commands. It could be done, but it would be arcane and slow.

I have written a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called parseCSV.bat, and a batch macro called csvGetCol](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5702) that make it simple and efficient for FOR /F to safely parse nearly any CSV file. The code is pure script that will work on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the scripts. Also, there are multiple examples posted showing how to use the utilities.

Here is the code that could be used for the example in this question. The code below allows for commas, quotes, newlines, `!`, and `^` in the column values.

```
@echo off

:: Delayed expansion must be disabled during macro definition
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
call define_csvGetCol

set "filename=input.csv"

:: Delayed expansion must be enabled when using %csvGetCol%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('parseCSV /e /d ^<"%filename%"') do (
  %== Load and decode column values ==%
  %csvGetCol% A "," %%A
  %csvGetCol% B "," %%B
  %csvGetCol% C "," %%C
  %csvGetCol% D "," %%D
  %== Print results ==%
  echo a : !A!
  echo b : !B!
  echo c : !C!
  echo d : !D!
)
```

I recommend following the link above for more information. But below is the code for the two utilities.  I will post updates as needed to the DOSTips site. I can't promise that I will keep the code below up-to-date.

**parseCSV.bat**

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScrpt comment

::************ Documentation ***********
::parseCSV.bat version 1.0
:::
:::parseCSV  [/option]...
:::
:::  Parse stdin as CSV and write it to stdout in a way that can be safely
:::  parsed by FOR /F. All columns will be enclosed by quotes so that empty
:::  columns may be preserved. It also supports delimiters, newlines, and
:::  quotes within quoted values. Two consecutive quotes within a quoted value
:::  are converted into one quote.
:::
:::  Available options:
:::
:::    /I:string = Input delimiter. Default is a comma.
:::
:::    /O:string = Output delimiter. Default is a comma.
:::
:::    /E = Encode output delimiter in value as \D
:::         Encode newline in value as \N
:::         Encode backslash in value as \S
:::
:::    /D = Escape exclamation point and caret for delayed expansion
:::         ! becomes ^!
:::         ^ becomes ^^
:::
:::parseCSV  /?
:::
:::  Display this help
:::
:::parseCSV  /V
:::
:::  Display the version of parseCSV.bat
:::
:::parseCSV.bat was written by Dave Benham. Updates are available at the original
:::posting site: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5702
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if "%~1" equ "/?" (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A
  exit /b 0
)
if /i "%~1" equ "/V" (
  for /f "delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /bc:"::%~nx0 version " "%~f0"') do echo %%A
  exit /b 0
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0


************ JScript portion ***********/
var args     = WScript.Arguments.Named,
    stdin    = WScript.Stdin,
    stdout   = WScript.Stdout,
    escape   = args.Exists("E"),
    delayed  = args.Exists("D"),
    inDelim  = args.Exists("I") ? args.Item("I") : ",",
    outDelim = args.Exists("O") ? args.Item("O") : ",",
    quote    = false,
    ln, c, n;
while (!stdin.AtEndOfStream) {
  ln=stdin.ReadLine();
  if (!quote) stdout.Write('"');
  for (n=0; n<ln.length; n++ ) {
    c=ln.charAt(n);
    if (c == '"') {
      if (quote && ln.charAt(n+1) == '"') {
        n++;
      } else {
        quote=!quote;
        continue;
      }
    }
    if (c == inDelim && !quote) c='"'+outDelim+'"';
    if (escape) {
      if (c == outDelim) c="\\D";
      if (c == "\\") c="\\S";
    }
    if (delayed) {
      if (c == "!") c="^!";
      if (c == "^") c="^^";
    }
    stdout.Write(c);
  }
  stdout.Write( (quote) ? ((escape) ? "\\N" : "\n") : '"\n' );
}
```

**define_csvGetCol.bat**

```
::define_csvGetCol.bat version 1.0
::
:: Defines variable LF and macro csvGetCol to be used with
:: parseCSV.bat to parse nearly any CSV file.
::
:: This script must be called with delayedExpansion disabled.
::
:: The %csvGetCol% macro must be used with delayedExpansion enabled.
::
:: Example usage:
::
::   @echo off
::   setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
::   call define_csvGetCol
::   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::   for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%A in ('parseCSV /d /e ^<test.csv') do (
::     %== Load and decode column values ==%
::     %csvGetCol% A "," %%A
::     %csvGetCol% B "," %%B
::     %csvGetCol% C "," %%C
::     %== Display the result ==%
::     echo ----------------------
::     for %%V in (A B C) do echo %%V=!%%V!
::     echo(
::   )
::
:: Written by Dave Benham
::

:: Delayed expansion must be disabled during macro definition

:: Define LF to contain a linefeed (0x0A) character
set ^"LF=^

^" The empty line above is critical - DO NOT REMOVE

:: define a newline with line continuation
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

:: Define csvGetCol
:: %csvGetCol%  envVarName  "Delimiter"  FORvar
set csvGetCol=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion^&for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%1 in ("!args!") do (%\n%
  endlocal^&endlocal%\n%
  set "%%1=%%~3"!%\n%
  if defined %%1 (%\n%
    for %%L in ("!LF!") do set "%%1=!%%1:\N=%%~L!"%\n%
    set "%%1=!%%1:\D=%%~2!"%\n%
    set "%%1=!%%1:\S=\!"%\n%
  )%\n%
)) else setlocal disableDelayedExpansion ^& set args=
```